# MongoDB Charts access link

Tags: mongodb, charts

I've just finished setting up a Free Tier Cluster on MongoDB Atlas and wanted to play with MongoDB Charts so I followed the official installation guide.

It all went well (with a few glitches) but now I don't know where do I go to access the Charts Dashboard. It doesn't say anywhere. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB Charts beta runs as a web server in a Docker container, and it is exposed over port 80 on the host.

If you are logged into the host running the container you can simply go to http://localhost in a web browser.

If you are logged into a different machine, you can use the host's name or IP address. E.g. if the server is called "chartsserver" you would access it via http://chartsserver.

Comment: is there any way to change the port number ? I have conflict in my apache configuration on my mac (I don't know why it's displaying one of my local site unstead of mongodb charts ui). thanks for the help

Comment: @DanyM yes you can edit the Docker Compose file to expose a different external port number.